# iOS Device compatibility in AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

My application appeared in the app store. List of supported devices begins with iPhone 5S, iPhone 6, iPad Air 2, etc. . But i need iPhone 4, 4s?
My Deployment target is iOS 8.0
Build Settings -> Valid Architectures - arm64, armv7, armv7s

How can I add iPhone 4, 4S, 5, iPad 2, etc?

Help, please!

Comment: If you need iPhone 4 your deployment target needs to be iOS 7.1 or lower.

Comment: Does your architecture or Valid architecture in Build Settings specificaly states armv7s & arm64 ? The devices you link are all armv7  http://static1.squarespace.com/static/51adfbd9e4b095d664d9b869/t/5596a861e4b0eb5f837cf243/1435936865957/iOS_Support_Matrix_v3_2.pdf

Comment: My Valid architecture is - arm64, armv7, armv7s. So, maybe I need to try appear my application again in AppStore?